# NSXMLNode textWithStringValue with entity

Tags: objective-c, xml, macos

Creating NSXMLNode with string:

```
NSXMLNode *node1 = [NSXMLNode textWithStringValue:@"<"];
NSLog(@"node1=%@",node1);
NSXMLNode *node2 = [NSXMLNode textWithStringValue:@">"];
NSLog(@"node2=%@",node2);
```

produces the following output:

```
node1=&lt;
node2=>
```

1. Why is the "<" character escaped (i.e. converted into `"&lt;"`) while the ">" character is not?
2. Is this a bug?
3. Which node is handled correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To quote the [XML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax):

   > The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. [...] The right angle bracket (>) **may** be represented using the string " &gt ; ", and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either " &gt ; " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]> " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

   In short, there are circumstances in which > does not have to be escaped, such as if it appears in an attribute.
2. No.
3. Both are.

If you ask for the string [in canonical format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html), both characters will be escaped:

```
NSXMLNode *node3 = [NSXMLNode textWithStringValue:@">"];
NSLog(@"node3=%@",[node3 canonicalXMLStringPreservingComments:NO]);
```

Output:

```
node3=&gt;
```